# Java applet does not load - Error.click for details

Tags: java, applet

I've been experimenting with Java. I've got a sample applet from a book 
Core Java by Cay Horstmann and Gary Cornell.

I've tried several options to open this, but I keep getting an error `Error.click for details`. then `Application blocked. Click for details` `Your security settings blocked application from running`.

I cannot run it from IE or Mozilla. In Netbeans I get a `no main class found` notification.

I'm wondering if something is wrong with the code, or with my settings.

I will appreciate any hints.

Here is my WelcomeApplet.java file:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * This applet displays a greeting from the authors.
 * @version 1.22 2007-04-08
 * @author Cay Horstmann
 */
public class WelcomeApplet extends JApplet
{
   public void init()
   {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
     {
        public void run()
        {
           setLayout(new BorderLayout());

           JLabel label = new JLabel(getParameter("greeting"), SwingConstants.CENTER);
           label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
           add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

           JPanel panel = new JPanel();

           JButton cayButton = new JButton("Cay Horstmann");
           cayButton.addActionListener(makeAction("http://www.horstmann.com"));
           panel.add(cayButton);

           JButton garyButton = new JButton("Gary Cornell");
           garyButton.addActionListener(makeAction("mailto:gary_cornell@apress.com"));
           panel.add(garyButton);

           add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
     });
   }

   private ActionListener makeAction(final String urlString)
   {
      return new ActionListener()
         {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
               try
               {
                  getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL(urlString));
               }
               catch (MalformedURLException e)
               {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
         };
   }
}
```

Then the applet code WelcomeApplet.html :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>WelcomeApplet</title>
       </head>
   <body>
      <hr/>
      <p>
         This applet is from the book 
         <a href="http://www.horstmann.com/corejava.html">Java. Podstawy</a>, 
         with authors <em>Cay Horstmann</em> and <em>Gary Cornell</em>,
         wydanej przez wydawnictwo Helion.
      </p>
  <applet code="WelcomeApplet.class" width="400" height="200">
     <param name="greeting" value="Witaj, czytelniku!"/>
  </applet>
  <hr/>
  <p><a href="WelcomeApplet.java">Source.</a></p>
```

and there is additional file java.policy.applet

```
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Tue Apr 16 17:20:59 EDT 2002*/
/* DO NOT EDIT */

grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Comment: The code and book are seven years old.   It's likely that you'll have problems, depending on the JVM/JRE you're using.  Why bother with applets?  They're so 1995.

Comment: Well, that's apparently a new edition of this book, so hopefully the code should be still valid... I need to learn this for my studies :) There is so many things to learn, but I like to do it step by step

Comment: Skip the applet step.  Nobody cares about them anymore.  I like that book, but don't waste a moment on that chapter.

Comment: I thought I would get a reply, and I still need to understand how applets work. But probably I need to wait with this until I get more basics, as there might be various reasons I don't comprehend in this code yet. Thank you anyways for reaching out.

Comment: *"I still need to understand how applets work."*  No you don't.  Really..  See [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) for the views of the top applet answerer on SO (me).

Comment: Ok Guys, I can drop this topic and live without it for some time, maybe I will never use it, we'll see. Many thanks.